# Vue.js + jQuery inputmask not working

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to use inputmask plugin as a Vue.js directive, but I'm getting the following error:

```
$(...).inputmask is not a function
```

After passing this error, I'll need the input value to be updated to the model (data.amount).

Here's the code (JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rL09zg5c/3/)

```
//HTML
<div id="app" class="container">
  <h1>
    Vue {{ vueVersion }}
  </h1>
  <form>
    <h3>
Currency:
    </h3>
    <input type="text" v-model="amount" v-input-mask/>
        <h4>
        Entered: {{ amount }}
        </h4>
  </form>
</div>

//JS
onload = function() {
  Vue.directive('input-mask', {
    bind: function(el, obj, vModel) {
            $(el).inputmask({
        prefix: 'R$ ',
        alias: 'numeric',
        allowMinus: false,
        groupSeparator: '.',
        radixPoint: ',',
        autoGroup: true,
        digits: 2,
        digitsOptional: false,
        placeholder: '0',
        rightAlign: false,
      });
    }
  })

  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      vueVersion: Vue.version,
      amount: ""
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: it seems you did not includes the libraries files correctly.

Comment: @Sphinx what exactly do you mean? Am I missing some library file?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you I think. [GitHub](https://github.com/m-a-k-o/vue-mask/blob/master/mask.js)

Usage:

```
Vue.use(Inputmask)

<input v-inputmask="'9999'">

<input v-inputmask="mask">
```

Comment: Do you have an example using this wrapper passing the inputmask options object, instead of only declaring the mask in the `v-input` attribute?

Comment: I updated answer. When you use string you have to use quotes or it will be evaluated as variable to your are free to use both. So it can be dynamic easily.

Comment: thanks, but it still isn't what I need. I don't want to pass options in the attribute for every input on the screen. I want to set the mask options just once, and then have it working for all the inputs.

Comment: Then you have to create component when you will wrap v-inputmask with some string as input.